# Using C# instead of XAML in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Is XAML really necessary?  If someone really wanted to, could everything displayed on a Silverlight page be declared at runtime in the C# code?
VISIFire has example code where they set up one of their classes, chart, in the C# code and then simply add it to the user interface with a simple C# call:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(chart);
```

How would I do a similar creation with a class I already have defined in the XAML file but because of other reasons I need to declare it at runtime?  If I could use it as it is in XAML I think it would work because there are no errors with its display.  It is declared like this:

```
        <views:PrescriberPage01 x:Name="DashboardPrescriberPage01" 
    Visibility="Collapsed" SelectedProduct="{Binding SelectedProduct,
 Mode=TwoWay}"Grid.Row ="0"/>
```

How would I declare that in C# code?

Comment: XAML is preferable  to describe user interface, in declarative way

Comment: XAML not only for developers, but also for designers.  
 What do you think, how designer will change style of control from code? Why he/she must learn C# or VB.Net?   
If you need to see your control and you are working only with C# code, then you can see control only by running application.  
And one more thing. Try to use binding from code and from XAML. You must see how many code you will need to write for it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is XAML really necessary?

I suppose no, you can probably do everything that you can do in XAML in code. But XAML is really, really a much, much more convenient way to go. And I think few would dissagree with this.

> How would I declare that in C# code?

You can create bindings in code. [Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx). In your situation it would be something like:

```
PrescriberPage01 page = new PrescriberPage01();
page.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Binding myBinding = new Binding("SelectedProduct");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.Source = this; // or whatever object carrying the property
                         // "SelectedProduct" that you bind against.

page.SetBinding(PrescriberPage01.SelectedProduct, myBinding);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(page);
```

Answer (score 1):

XAML is preferable  to describe user interface, in declarative way and I recommend use XAML without code behind and also I would recommend look at MVVM pattern

Answer (score 1):

I would rather say "Is C# really necessary for GUIs when I can use XAML" ? XAML is really good and was explicitly design for GUI.

You have two options here. Load your [XAML dynamicly](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/09/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-60-how-to-load-a-control-straight-from-xaml.aspx).

Or create it in code. (other posted the solution while i was typing AGAIN! ;) )

Comment: +1 for '"Is C# really necessary for GUIs when I can use XAML" ?'

Answer (score 0):

Simple controls are easy but... you might also want some styling done to those objects +
you might want an animation or two... this is already(mostly) provided in xaml ... and it is uber easy... If u hate xaml so much you might want to think about "Blend";p

Answer (score 0):

One specific example of something you can't create without Xaml is a DataTemplate.

You can write code which will create a DataTemplate from a XAML string, but you can't add children to a newed up DataTemplate directly in c#.